# Prevent 'mouseenter' callback function untill 'highlight' effect is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, highlight, mouseenter

I am having a similar issue as in the snippet below:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    var p = $('<p>Lorem</p>');
    $('body').prepend(p);
    p.effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});

$(document).on('mouseenter', 'p', function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'blue');
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', 'p', function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'white');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<button>Add</button>
```

As you can notice, as soon as the first `Lorem` is prepended to the body, `mouseenter` is allowed for a fraction of a second. As a result, you see the blue background to it.

This is affecting negatively on the UX.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    var p = $('<p>Lorem</p>');
    $('body').prepend(p);
  
    p.effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
  
    // give your new element a class
    p.addClass('noHover');
  
    // remove that class after the animation
    setTimeout(function() { p.removeClass('noHover'); }, 3000);
    // from my testing, you could probably stand to take the `3000` down to `2500` 
    // but I leave that to you
});

$(document).on('mouseenter', 'p', function(){
  
    // check for the added class
    if(!$(this).hasClass('noHover')){
      
        //only allow the blue hover effect if the 'noHover' class has been removed
        $(this).css('background', 'blue');
    }
  
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', 'p', function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'white');
});
```

```css
#myBtn{ margin-top:22px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<button id="myBtn">Add</button>
```

Comment: Suppose I added the first `Lorem`. The cursor kinda automatically comes over it because the button moves down. Is there a way that I can get its background to blue while the cursor is over it and the `noHover` class has been removed?

Comment: Hmm, apparently that's harder than it sounds. I would say just add `if( p.is(":hover")){ p.css('background', 'blue'); } ` inside the timer after we remove the class, but that doesnt work because the  first `Lorem` gets added under the cursor which is not the same thing as the user hovering. Id say give the button an id and use css to give it a top margin ensuring that the user's cursor is doesnt land above the first `Lorem` like `#myBtn{ margin-top:22px; }` , edited the above with this in mind